# Creation of Apple push notifications certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, csr

I'm creating a CSR certificate and using that CSR to create a push notification certificate.

Can I use the same CSR for different certificates?

Also, my provisioning profile goes to invalid state even though I didn't add any new devices to account. Why is that?

Comment: "my provisioning profile goes to invalid state" what you mean by that ?

Comment: see my Screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yhmf3wlhvwslkd/invalid.png?dl=0

Comment: Check whether certificate is selected or not in provisioning profile, by just editing it. Also check multiple certificates are there or not

Comment: the distribution certificate is selected, there is only one certificate in my case which is distribution certificate

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use same CSR for different certificates. However, they would end up having same private key, which is actually not a security issue if you are not going to give your certificate to anyone else anyway.

Comment: is that CSR is useful in the future, can i delete it?

Comment: For Apple, you can delete it. It is quite easy to make a new one for replacement, and certificate will expire in only one year anyway.

Comment: once CSR  expires, all the Certiiccates related to those will expire. Am I correct?